# System.BadImageFormatException error

Tags: c#, asp.net

**I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter 64-bit OS. I am using Visual Studio 2013 that has a solution with 2 projects and I am encountering this error.**

> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'EyeCantSeeEngine' or one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'EyeCantSeeEngine' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = EyeCantSeeEngine  (Partial) WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an
>   assembly: WRN: Assembly Name: EyeCantSeeEngine | Domain ID: 2 WRN: A
>   partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is
>   provided. WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect
>   assembly. WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual
>   identity for the assembly, WRN: that consists of the simple name,
>   version, culture, and public key token. WRN: See whitepaper
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and
>   common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/ISFC_Main/EyeCantSee/EyeCantSeeEngine/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ISFC_Main\EyeCantSee\EyeCantSeeEngine\bin
>
> Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>
> LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application
>   configuration file:
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ISFC_Main\EyeCantSee\EyeCantSeeEngine\web.config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Users\uni\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/uni/AppData/Local/Temp/1/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/b917a818/774df716/EyeCantSeeEngine.DLL. LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/uni/AppData/Local/Temp/1/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/b917a818/774df716/EyeCantSeeEngine/EyeCantSeeEngine.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/ISFC_Main/EyeCantSee/EyeCantSeeEngine/bin/EyeCantSeeEngine.DLL.
>   ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing
>   terminated.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'EyeCantSeeEngine' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to
>   load a program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +34
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +16    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'EyeCantSeeEngine' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to
>   load a program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +218    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +130
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +170
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +91    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +285
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'EyeCantSeeEngine' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to
>   load a program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9950728 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

**I have tried changing the target platform of the project of the error from x64 to x86 and the error that I encounter next is this.**

> Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'
>   was thrown.]    System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +34
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +16    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +218    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +130
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +170
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +91    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +285
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9950728 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

I have also tried changing the Enable 32-bit Applications in the IIS Application Pools to True but the System.BadImageFormatException error still persist. Greatly appreciated for any suggestions to solve this error.

Comment: Have you recycled your application pools? Done a complete rebuild of all projects?

Answer (score 0):

BadImageFormatException usually means architecture conflits.. Like trying to install a 32 bit assembly with a x64 install util for example.

Also in the pre-bind state information you can read this line:

> WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name
>   is provided.
>   WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.

Which might indicate that you are not using a fully qualified name to load an assembly but just the type. Try specifying the fully qualified name of the assembly you are trying to load.